# export data set to csv file using C#

Tags: c#-3.0

how to export Data from sql server into csv file using c#

Eg;

Select name,id from employee

Name     id

XXX      1
  ZZZ      2
  AAA      3

This result will be stored in the CSV File.

Comment: Can you at least provide a query for the data you need to export?

Answer (score 8):

Using [Filehelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) and [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")] 
public class Employee 
{ 
    public string Name;
    public int Id; 
}
```

In some method somewhere:

```
var employees = connection.Query<Employee>("select Name, Id from employee");
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Employee));
engine.WriteFile("employees.csv", employees);
```

Comment: To include headers in the CSV as well, add this line before writing to file `engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();`