# Using Dapper I want to write a CSV text file reading an Instrument table from sql database with Console.WriteLine

Tags: sql-server, csv, dapper, csvhelper

Using https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) I'm trying to write a csv text file with the Console.WriteLine output from an Instrument table connected to sqlserver using Dapper.

my initial code to open DB and process records is

```
using (var dbconn = new SqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString))
        {
            var fred = dbconn.Query<Instrument>("SELECT * FROM Instruments");
            foreach (var s in fred)

            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{s.SurgicalDeviceId}, {s.CreatedAt}");
```

Now i've been reading up on this and a few people have said by using Console.WriteLine I can make a simple and clean code to create the csv file but I seem to be having no luck trying it myself.

Could anyone help write the code or point me in the direction where this has been done with Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Console.Writeline simple writes out information to the "Console"...or command-window...it will not write a file.     Also, since are you new, you may want to read this URL....so you don't start out spaghetti coding everything : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cossdk/using-a-three-tier-architecture-model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991896/export-data-set-to-csv-file-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CsvHelper to write the records to file.csv, this should work for you.

```cs
using (var dbconn = new SqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString))
        {
            var records = dbconn.Query<Instrument>("SELECT * FROM Instruments").ToList();

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
            }
```

Comment: @KuroKami If that answer worked for you. You should mark it as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers